ESP32, ArduinoJSON and MQTT: Stuck in process chain
I have some trouble for a while with my application and can not figure out why the ESP32 get stuck in the processing chain. The issue randomly occurs after 3 or 4 weeks in production mode. Sometimes after 1 week. It's hard to tell.

UPDATE
It's probably some kind of a memory leak. I updated the code and don't expect any memory leak anymore.

So first, let me explain how the process chain looks like.
On ESP startup, the MQTT client (AsyncMQTT_Generic Library) connects to the MQTT broker Mosquitto, subscribes to the topic esp/config/<ESP32_WIFI_MAC_ADDRESS>, receives a message payload as a JSON object
{"idsl":900000000,"dsle":true,"ihttp":1800000,"time":1712487701726,"addr":["C4:7C:8D:6D:31:2A"],"syse":true}

that is deserialized by ArduinoJson (version 6.21.5) and stores it to the RTC storage rtcConfig of ESP32 as follows:
#define MAC_ADDR_LENGTH 18
#define MAX_BLE_NUMBER 5

const char* MQTT_TOPIC_CONFIG = "esp/config/";

char* topicConfigMac;

struct RtcData {
    unsigned int wakeupCnt;
    uint32_t channel;
    uint8_t bssid[6];
    uint8_t systemEnabled;
    uint8_t deepSleepEnabled;
    uint64_t deepSleepInterv;
    uint32_t httpRequestInterv;
    uint8_t hasConfig;
    uint64_t time;
    char bleAddr[MAX_BLE_NUMBER][MAC_ADDR_LENGTH];
};

// Real Time Clock memory
RTC_DATA_ATTR RtcData rtcConfig;

StaticJsonDocument<512> jsonConfig;

// Receiving MQTT message from topic
void onMqttMessage(char* topic, char* payload, const AsyncMqttClientMessageProperties& properties,
    const size_t& len, const size_t& index, const size_t& total) {

    Serial.printf("MQTT received message on topic '%s'\n", topic);
    Serial.printf("  QoS: %u", properties.qos);
    Serial.printf(", dup: %d", properties.dup);
    Serial.printf(", retain: %d", properties.retain);
    Serial.printf(", len: %u", len);
    Serial.printf(", index: %u", index);
    Serial.printf(", total: %u\n", total);

    if (strcmp(topic, topicConfigMac) == 0) {
        deserializePayload(payload);
    } else {
        Serial.printf("MQTT received message topic %s is unequal to %s\n", topic, topicConfigMac);
        enterSleepMode();
    }
}

void deserializePayload(char* payload) {
    Serial.print("Deserialize payload: ");
    jsonConfig.clear();
    DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(jsonConfig, payload);

    if (error) {
        Serial.printf("failed: %s", error.c_str());
        return;
    } else {
        size_t size = serializeJson(jsonConfig, Serial); // printing JSON to Serial for debugging
        Serial.printf(", %u bytes\n", size);

        // Returns false on initial boot as expected
        // Should return true after storing configuration to RTC
        if (isConfigUpToDate()) {
            Serial.println("Configuration is up-to-date");
            publishSensorData();
        } else {
            storeConfigToRtc();
            reboot = true;
            mqttClient.disconnect();
            // Rebooting ESP32; After reboot subscribe to topic again
            // Now, we use the configuration stored in RTC storage
            // isConfigUpToDate() should return true
        }
    }
}

bool isConfigUpToDate() {
    // Is this a valid statement to compare a uint64_t with jsonConfig?
    return rtcConfig.time > 0 && rtcConfig.time == (uint64_t)jsonConfig["time"];
}

void storeConfigToRtc() {
    Serial.println("Store payload to RTC");
    rtcConfig.hasConfig = true;
    rtcConfig.systemEnabled = jsonConfig["syse"];
    rtcConfig.deepSleepEnabled = jsonConfig["dsle"];
    rtcConfig.deepSleepInterv = jsonConfig["idsl"];
    rtcConfig.httpRequestInterv = jsonConfig["ihttp"];
    rtcConfig.time = jsonConfig["time"];
    // BLE addresses
    JsonArray bleAddresses = jsonConfig["addr"].as<JsonArray>();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < MAX_BLE_NUMBER; i++) {
        if (i < bleAddresses.size()) {
            String addr = bleAddresses[i].as<String>();
            strcpy(rtcConfig.bleAddr[i], addr.c_str());
        } else {
            strcpy(rtcConfig.bleAddr[i], "\0");
        }
    }
}

void resetRtc() {
    Serial.println("Reset RTC data");
    rtcConfig.hasConfig = false;
    rtcConfig.systemEnabled = false;
    rtcConfig.deepSleepEnabled = true;
    rtcConfig.deepSleepInterv = 60000000;
    rtcConfig.httpRequestInterv = 60000;
    rtcConfig.time = 0;
    rtcConfig.bleAddr[MAX_BLE_NUMBER][MAC_ADDR_LENGTH] = { 0 };
}

void setup() {
    ...
    if (rtcConfig.wakeupCnt == 0) {
        resetRtc();
    }
    ...
    topicConfigMac = (char*)malloc(strlen(MQTT_TOPIC_CONFIG) + MAC_ADDR_LENGTH);
    strcpy(topicConfigMac, MQTT_TOPIC_CONFIG);
    strcat(topicConfigMac, WiFi.macAddress().c_str());
    ...
}

void loop() {}

Because rtcConfig.time is 0 initially, isConfigUpToDate() returns false and stores the configuration into RTC after that. After a reboot, rtcConfig.time is not 0 anymore and should publish the sensor data to the MQTT server.
From the log files of Mosquitto and analyses, I can tell that the process get stuck on the above method isConfigUpToDate() which will return false after the first expected reboot. But I'm expecting true at this point.
Now, I'm not sure why it get stuck there. There can be several reasons:
Is the logical expression
rtcConfig.time > 0 && rtcConfig.time == (uint64_t)jsonConfig["time"]

technically valid at all time?
Is there any way to confirm without USB debugging that the received JSON attribute time is set as I expect it to be?
Unfortunately, I can not debug the issue via USB port in 'production mode' because it's powered by a battery and solar panel. If I debug it via USB port, the issue never occurs probably because I'm not patient enough to wait for the failing iteration. It only occurs after 3 or 4 weeks in production mode. Sometimes after 1 week. It's hard to tell.
Any idea or input is appreciated! I'm facing the issue over months and can not get rid of it...
Thanks in advance
EDIT
In the following, here is a valid Mosquitto log where everything just works fine:
2024-04-07 04:46:27: New connection from 192.168.178.36:61317 on port 1883.
2024-04-07 04:46:27: New client connected from 192.168.178.36:61317 as esp_dev (p2, c1, k15, u'esp32').
2024-04-07 04:46:27: No will message specified.
2024-04-07 04:46:27: Sending CONNACK to esp_dev (0, 0)
2024-04-07 04:46:27: Received SUBSCRIBE from esp_dev
2024-04-07 04:46:27:    esp/config/0C:B8:15:F4:1F:FC (QoS 1)
2024-04-07 04:46:27: esp_dev 1 esp/config/0C:B8:15:F4:1F:FC
2024-04-07 04:46:27: Sending SUBACK to esp_dev
2024-04-07 04:46:27: Sending PUBLISH to esp_dev (d0, q0, r1, m0, 'esp/config/0C:B8:15:F4:1F:FC', ... (108 bytes))
2024-04-07 04:46:27: Received PUBLISH from esp_dev (d0, q1, r0, m2, 'testTopic', ... (86 bytes))
2024-04-07 04:46:27: Sending PUBLISH to paho82806266301 (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'testTopic', ... (86 bytes))
2024-04-07 04:46:27: Sending PUBACK to esp_dev (m2, rc0)
2024-04-07 04:46:27: Received DISCONNECT from esp_dev
2024-04-07 04:46:27: Client esp_dev disconnected.

And this is the failing Mosquitto log where it gets stuck in an infinite loop. Here you can see that the ESP is actively disconnecting from the broker after receiving the published message. This must be the code in deserializePayload() if isConfigUpToDate() returns false. After 5-7 seconds, it will do it again and again.
2024-04-07 05:31:34: New connection from 192.168.178.36:51254 on port 1883.
2024-04-07 05:31:34: New client connected from 192.168.178.36:51254 as esp_dev (p2, c1, k15, u'esp32').
2024-04-07 05:31:34: No will message specified.
2024-04-07 05:31:34: Sending CONNACK to esp_dev (0, 0)
2024-04-07 05:31:34: Received SUBSCRIBE from esp_dev
2024-04-07 05:31:34:    esp/config/0C:B8:15:F4:1F:FC (QoS 1)
2024-04-07 05:31:34: esp_dev 1 esp/config/0C:B8:15:F4:1F:FC
2024-04-07 05:31:34: Sending SUBACK to esp_dev
2024-04-07 05:31:34: Sending PUBLISH to esp_dev (d0, q0, r1, m0, 'esp/config/0C:B8:15:F4:1F:FC', ... (108 bytes))
2024-04-07 05:31:34: Received DISCONNECT from esp_dev
2024-04-07 05:31:34: Client esp_dev disconnected.
2024-04-07 05:31:40: New connection from 192.168.178.36:60107 on port 1883.
2024-04-07 05:31:41: New client connected from 192.168.178.36:60107 as esp_dev (p2, c1, k15, u'esp32').
2024-04-07 05:31:41: No will message specified.
2024-04-07 05:31:41: Sending CONNACK to esp_dev (0, 0)
2024-04-07 05:31:41: Received SUBSCRIBE from esp_dev
2024-04-07 05:31:41:    esp/config/0C:B8:15:F4:1F:FC (QoS 1)
2024-04-07 05:31:41: esp_dev 1 esp/config/0C:B8:15:F4:1F:FC
2024-04-07 05:31:41: Sending SUBACK to esp_dev
2024-04-07 05:31:41: Sending PUBLISH to esp_dev (d0, q0, r1, m0, 'esp/config/0C:B8:15:F4:1F:FC', ... (108 bytes))
2024-04-07 05:31:41: Received DISCONNECT from esp_dev
...
infinite loop here until the battery is drained from WiFi connecting
...

mosquitto.conf
...
autosave_interval 1800
autosave_on_changes true
persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/
...


To assist with debugging consider publishing the value of rtcConfig.time back to the broker. I cannot see an error in your logic (but the rtcConfig.time > 0 check seems fairly pointless if you know that jsonConfig["time"] is not 0). Note that I'm assuming that the JSON received is unchanged.

I'm not sure that I understand the design logic. The rtcConfig.time stored in the RTC_DATA is the time that previous parsed/deserialized from a received json object before the reboot, after the reboot, a new json object is received and deserialised as jsonConfig["time"] so how could this time equal to the previous stored time in rtcConfig.time? so rtcConfig.time > 0 && rtcConfig.time == (uint64_t)jsonConfig["time"] will of course return false.

@Brits: Publishing the JSON config to a new debug topic is a good idea. I'll try that. Regarding to rtcConfig.time > 0: This makes actually no sense, you're right.

@hcheung: rtcConfig.time represents the time when the config was last updated in the database. It's not the current timestamp. After reboot, you might get the same JSON object if the user did not modify the config.
The variable name is not the best, true. lastUpdated or modifiedOn would be better.

"only occurs after 3 or 4 weeks in production mode" I'd suggest stating this at the start of the question! See how you get on with publishing some debug messages via MQTT; if this does not help I think we will need a bit more info (i.e. what are you seeing in the broker logs, do things work OK when you manually cycle the power, how is the config sent - persistent message?, how did you confirm the process gets stuck in this function, ideally the MQTT code - often this kind of issue is not where you expect it to be!).

I've added the mosquitto logs and mosquitto.conf. The config is a retained message at QoS 1. If Spring Boot gets initialized, it populates all MQTT config topics with the corresponding config as a retained message at QoS 1, so there should be always a message in the queue. Please look at the mosquitto.conf. I'm really not sure if the broker runs with the correct configuration and what is exactly does.

I've implemented a debug topic where the config is republished. Let's see. Thanks by the way for your responds, @Brits and @hcheung!

Mosquitto config looks fine and, as you say, the logs indicate that the retained message is delivered (at QOS 0). Will be interested to see what you get on the debug topic.

The issue actually occured on the first boot of the ESP after my updated code. The debug topic was filled with time = 0 and repeated after 5-7 seconds. If I power off and power on the ESP again, the issue disappeared... first time = 0 then time = 1712653816912 as expected. I don't see any pattern there so I guess, I'm running in some kind of memory leak?!

Probably (difficult to say as we only have a small portion of the code). However it's interesting that it happened immediately this time which seems to indicate that it's not a slow leak (would expect this to take a similar amount of time to manifest each time). I'd guess its an out of bounds memory write (e.g. the memset in the question looks wrong to me, you are starting part way through the array but clearing sizeof(rtcConfig.bleAddr)).

Oh, I think, you're right. I changed the code and removed the statement with memset because I think, it's actually not necessary because of the initialization of the array. Can you check out the code at the end of my question, please? I'm really not an expert in C/C++ and had a lot of trouble with that. ^^

strcpy copies the null at the end of the string so I don't think it's necessary to set this in the way you are (and it's possible there are other chars between the end of the string and the end of the buffer).

I updated the code accordingly. From my point of view, I don't expect any memory leak anymore. Thanks you for now for your time. Really appreciated!

Since, I updated the code due to the memory leak, no more errors occurred in this context. I removed the instruction memset because it corrupted the RTC memory.
So I'm closing the thread. Thanks @Brits for helping me out, cheers!
